# Error while trying to set up orchard site

Tags: orchardcms

Tried setting up site in orchard got the following can anyone help

> > The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope. 
> >     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web >>request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it >>originated in the code.
> >
> > Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The connection object can not be >>enlisted in transaction scope.
> >
> > Source Error:
> >
> > Line 332:            contentItemCriteria.SetCacheable(true);
> >     Line 333:
> >     Line 334:            return contentItemVersionCriteria.List();
> >     Line 335:        }
> >     Line 336: